# Why doesn't the universe look symmetrical?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, symmetry, universe

If the universe was a dot lets say a point, and that dot expanded equally from all sides, then shouldn't the universe look more symmetric, maybe indentical, from that dot all around?

Comment: The universe is surprisingly homogeneous and isotropic, despite our daily experience at such a small length scale (compared with the size of universe). See this link: http://www.universeadventure.org/big_bang/expand-balance.htm

Comment: Try this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_breaking 
There is some interest now in anisotropy in cosmic microwave background, for example. There seems to be a lot of matter, for example, and not very much antimatter (although this is not a directional asymmetry ).

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in the fact that the expansion of the universe is a lot more subtle than that. The currently accepted model of the universe doesn't require the universe to have been located at one point. Instead, it requires that, at every point in the universe, the energy density was very large. The expansion of the universe then simply says that if I put two indestructible and non-interacting balls one meter apart (shortly after whatever the Big Bang singularity actually was) from each other, as time goes on their distance would increase as time goes on. It is worth noting that there is not a single point from which the universe is expanding. **The universe expands everywhere all at once.**

Now to answer the question: the current models used to describe the expansion of the universe are a mixture of classical gravity (General Relativity) and quantum mechanics (specifically, field theory). Classical gravity on its own predicts that the universe would expand isotropically and uniformly. However, quantum mechanics is a different beast and allows the relative energy density to fluctuate in places. These fluctuations were small at first, but they then would influence the spacetime geometry around it, thus causing high-energy fluctuations to clump together. These fluctuations are actually what give the famous picture of the Planck-data CMB (shown below) its red and yellow spots.

[image]

While these spots look highly contrasted to the rest of the background, the actual variation in the temperature shown is less than one part per hundred thousand.

This clumping continued and, as space expanded, they became larger and more prominent. Eventually, as the story goes, they become the large-scale structures we see today (planets, stars, galaxies, etc.) and are responsible for the asymmetry that we see in the universe.

To close, I want to make it clear that, on extreme scales, the universe is pretty damn homogeneous and, on less extreme but pretty damn big scales, it is isotropic. The local structure of the universe is simply (as far as we can tell, although there are still problems and discrepancies that arise in the modern research of structure formation) a consequence of the random nature of quantum mechanics and is still incredibly tiny compared to the scales at which expansion actually occurs.